# Trying to play sound but it is not working

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-code, audio

How to play sound using C++ in VSCode?

This is my program:

[image]

My error is:

> undefined reference to `__imp_PlaySoundA'

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And *please* don't post images of text, least of all code. Copy-paste text as text into your questions.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, or links to pictures of text - post the text. (I'm constantly amazed that, these days, posting screenshots to an image-sharing site is apparently a more basic skill than copy and paste.)

Comment: As for your problem, have you read [the `PlaySound` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85))? Besides telling you that the function is deprecated, it does tell you which library you need to link with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude `PlaySound()` is old, but it is not deprecated, and nowhere in that documentation does it say that it is.

Comment: @som No longer regularly updating API documentation is distinctly different from deprecating an API. You apparently mistook the former for the latter.

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion, I seems to have confused that API with other (now deprecated and obsolete) API's. However, the solution is in the documentation.